# Creating a query/SQL in Access for a date for multiple tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

The database is about a company and the positions involved. For this specific question, I'm asked for the number of positions listed in the database for each firm (open, filled, and expired positions).

The result should be the name of each firm and the total number of their positions. Additional information includes 'Assume current date is 05/03/2005. A position is open if the current date is in-between the start and end date for the position
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
I'm just having trouble using the right SQL/Query to get the correct answer.

I used the code below but I don't think it's right:

```sql
SELECT
    CF.Client_Name AS Firm_Name,
    SUM(IIF(P.Position_StartDate <= #05/03/2005# AND P.Position_EndDate >= #05/03/2005#, 1, 0)) AS Open_Positions,
    SUM(IIF(P.Filled_Position = 'Yes', 1, 0)) AS Filled_Positions,
    SUM(IIF(P.Expired_Position = 'Yes', 1, 0)) AS Expired_Positions,
    COUNT(P.Position_ID) AS Total_Positions
FROM
    Client_Firms CF
INNER JOIN
    Position P ON CF.Client_ID = P.Client_ID
GROUP BY
    CF.Client_Name;
```

Edit: I was able to solve this! Thank you!

Comment: From our perspective, unless you face a syntax error we don't know what is correct or not in terms of data. Please explain the issue with your attempted SQL. Are you receiving errors? No data? Doubling of results?

Comment: Sorry. I get a syntax error for using From or it claims I missing operators.

Comment: Please post the full exact message of error. Did you search online for exact message? Consider [researching](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) before posting!

Comment: Are Filled_Position and Expired_Position text data type or Yes/No data type fields? If Yes/No, don't use apostrophe delimiters. Would not even need Yes: `Sum(IIf(P.Expired_Position, 1, 0))`. Your narrative says there is one field `Position` with values of Open, Filled, Expired - yet you show 2 Position fields in query. Edit question to show sample data as formatted text table.

Comment: To get an answer faster, you should supplement the question with information with initial data like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77511548/sql-join-with-or-and-list
or (it would be great!) like this:
WITH ITEM (id , name) AS (
   SELECT  1,   'Apple' UNION ALL
   SELECT 2,    'Banana' UNION ALL
   SELECT 3,    'Orange' )
select * from ITEM

Comment: Correction, I now presume by "Categories" you mean "Fields". So you do have multiple Position fields? I cannot see anything wrong with the SQL syntax. Did you use Access query designer to construct query?

Comment: @ellen Your SQL references fields named `Filled_Position` and `Expired_Position` in the `Position` table.  But the image does not show either of those fields in that table.  Please clarify.  TIA.

Comment: @HansUp I think part of the assignment was to add those fields. I'm not 100% sure but the question it's asking is the values in Open, Filled, Expired. That's why I added them in my code but I'm probably wrong

Comment: I think, should be ``SUM(IIF( P.Position_EndDate < #05/03/2005#, 1, 0)) AS Expired__Positions``  and ``SUM(IIF(P.JoobSeeker_Id IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)) AS Filled_Positions`` .     Expired_Position and Filled_Position do not exist is schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no visible issue with your posted SQL using the MS Access dialect, the remaining culprit can be the [reserved word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sql-reserved-words-b899948b-0e1c-4b56-9622-a03f8f07cfc8), `Position`. Ideally, database developers should avoid using reserved words for table and columns  names. Without escaping, reserved words can cause problematic issues with query engine. In Microsoft Access, you can escape such identifiers with square brackets or backticks:

```sql
FROM
    Client_Firms CF
INNER JOIN
    [Position] P ON CF.Client_ID = P.Client_ID
```

```sql
FROM
    Client_Firms CF
INNER JOIN
    `Position` P ON CF.Client_ID = P.Client_ID
```

---

By the way, for portability and clarity use the ANSI date format of `YYYY-MM-DD` for dates and not the day-first or month-first that varies across locales. Even use the `CDate()` for a more functional form solution which can take parameterized strings. Also, you can avoid calling `IIF` by directly summing the logical expressions. But since `True` in Access is equal to -1, multiply the results by -1 for actual counts:

```sql
SELECT
    CF.Client_Name AS Firm_Name,
    SUM(P.Position_StartDate <= #2005/05/03# AND P.Position_EndDate >= CDate('2005-05-03')) * -1 AS Open_Positions,
    SUM(P.Filled_Position = 'Yes') * -1 AS Filled_Positions,
    SUM(P.Expired_Position = 'Yes') * -1 AS Expired_Positions,
    COUNT(P.Position_ID) AS Total_Positions
FROM
    Client_Firms CF
INNER JOIN
    [Position] P ON CF.Client_ID = P.Client_ID
GROUP BY
    CF.Client_Name;
```

Comment: I used this method and the previous one to see what would happen. Is it normal to be prompted by a window that says 'Enter Parameter Value' for each of the positions I mentioned?

Comment: No, it is not normal and indicates those positions are not actually columns in the table. _Enter Parameter Value_ will raise an error outside of MSAccess.exe such as connecting to database via application code. From your schema, maybe you meant `P.Position_Name = 'Filled'`?