# SQL Join with OR/AND list?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table *works* like this:

| INTRAWORKNO | QUALIFICATION_REQ |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 999 |
| 2 | 999 |
| 3 | 999 |
| 0 | 101 |
| 9999 | 101 |

I have a table *PERS_ALLOWED*:

| PERSV | ALLOWED |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 999 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 999 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 101 |

As you see, in works.INTRAWORKNO, there is the index for the corresponding work. Each work has different qualifications required.
As you see in my example for works, the INTRAWORKNO 1 has three requirements of Qualification.
I want to join it with the PERS_ALLOWED table to find a qualificated worker.

So, INTRAWORKNO 1 needs a worker that has requirements like this condition: (1 OR 2) AND (999). So when the Qualification_REQ is lower than 100, these Qualifications should be connected with OR --> (Technican needs Qualification 1 OR 2) AND with AND (Technican needs Qualification 999 as minimum).

How can I do that?

Comment: You ommitted your desired results

Comment: Why can you not simply inner join the tables and take the distinct `persv`?

Comment: What is your DBMS? Always tag your SQL requests with your DBMS.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: I have SQL SERVER 2019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First cross join works and persons. (This is necessary, because we want to aggregate by work number and person and not lose a row there.) Then outer join the actual personal qualifications. Now count conditionally to see whether all required high qualifications have a match. For the check whether at least one low qualification is met when required, we could also count conditionally and have a case expression to sort things out, but it is even easier with `MAX`.

You haven't shown the desired result, so I have two queries for you.

Here is a query that shows all qualified candidates for a work:

```
select w.intraworkno, p.persv
from works w
cross join (select distinct persv from pers_allowed) p
left join pers_allowed pa on pa.allowed = w.qualification_req
                          and pa.persv = p.persv
group by w.intraworkno, p.persv
having count(case when pa.allowed > 99 then 1 end) =
       count(case when w.qualification_req > 99 then 1 end)
   and max(case when pa.allowed <= 99 then 1 else 0 end) >=
       max(case when w.qualification_req <= 99 then 1 else 0 end)
order by w.intraworkno, p.persv;
```

And here is a table showing all works with all persons tagged whether the person is qualified for the work or not.

```
select
  w.intraworkno, p.persv,
  (count(case when pa.allowed > 99 then 1 end) =
   count(case when w.qualification_req > 99 then 1 end)
    and
   max(case when pa.allowed <= 99 then 1 else 0 end) >=
   max(case when w.qualification_req <= 99 then 1 else 0 end)
  ) as is_qualified
from works w
cross join (select distinct persv from pers_allowed) p
left join pers_allowed pa on pa.allowed = w.qualification_req
                          and pa.persv = p.persv
group by w.intraworkno, p.persv
order by w.intraworkno, p.persv;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/z4s_tTIK

Comment: now i checked with a few different records - this is working

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but you lack integrity in the data and in the description of the data. Therefore, the answer should be double-checked for you personally.

---

To achieve this, you can use the following SQL query to join the `works` table with the `PERS_ALLOWED` table and find qualified workers for each work based on the qualifications required:

```sql
SELECT w.INTRAWORKNO, p.PERSV
FROM works w
JOIN (
    SELECT INTRAWORKNO, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN QUALIFICATION_REQ < 100 THEN QUALIFICATION_REQ END) AS low_qual,
    MAX(CASE WHEN QUALIFICATION_REQ >= 100 THEN QUALIFICATION_REQ END) AS high_qual
    FROM works
    GROUP BY INTRAWORKNO
) q
ON w.INTRAWORKNO = q.INTRAWORKNO
JOIN PERS_ALLOWED p
ON (w.QUALIFICATION_REQ < 100 AND p.ALLOWED = q.low_qual) OR 
   (w.QUALIFICATION_REQ >= 100 AND p.ALLOWED = q.high_qual)
```

This query first groups the `works` table by `INTRAWORKNO` and then selects the maximum low and high qualifications required for each work. It then joins this result with the `PERS_ALLOWED` table based on the condition you specified for qualification matching.

This query will return the `INTRAWORKNO` and the corresponding `PERSV` of qualified workers for each work based on the qualifications required.

Comment: @Lukas Fürst: I doubt that. Have you examined the query and understood what it does? Michael K says: "the answer should be double-checked". Have you? Look here: https://dbfiddle.uk/782pjuAk. In this demo, work #1 requires qualifications 1 and 999. Person #1 has these qualifications, person #2 doesn't. The query results in two rows showing person #1 as qualified and one row with person #2 qualified.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: As you said, i was a bit to fast and marked it has solved to early. The qualifications are not ranked, and this query leads to a ranking. Qualification 1 is different with Qualification 2, Qualification 2 is not higher than Qualification 1, its only different